Gui asks for input before asking a question
I have a gui script that I use to call other script and call outputs from it. Only thing that happens is that the prints get rendered, but when it hits the input, it asks for the answer from user first before it prints the question from the input. But I want him to write the question first and then demand an answer.
I think the problem is in the execute function, but I don't know what to do about it. My theory is that once the gui detects that it wants input from user, it switches to None and thus the condition in execute no longer applies and it can't render. But I don't know how to solve this. I am attaching below the script I am rendering:
import time

def choose_assignment():
    
    print("1. Mixing two liquids.")
    print("2. Dividing a larger volume into x beakers.")
    print("To select, enter a digit without a dot on the following line")
    assignment = int(input("Write the digit you choose:"))
    print("ahoj")
    print(f"You chose option {assignment}.")
    a = input("ahoj: ")
    print(a)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(1)  # Simulate some delay
    choose_assignment()

and Gui script
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time


class Console(tk.Frame):
    """Simple console that can execute bash commands"""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text_options = {
            "state": "disabled",
            "bg": "black",
            "fg": "#08c614",
            "insertbackground": "#08c614",
            "selectbackground": "#f01c1c"
        }

        self.text = ScrolledText(self, **self.text_options)
        self.text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.command = ""  # Predefined command (script path)
        self.popen = None  # Will hold a reference to a Popen object
        self.running = False  # True if the process is running

        self.bottom = tk.Frame(self)

        # Input field for user input
        self.input_entry = tk.Entry(self.bottom, width=80)
        self.input_entry.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)
        self.input_entry.bind("<Return>", self.send_input)

        # Button to start the script
        self.executer = tk.Button(self.bottom, text="Start Script", command=self.start_thread)
        self.executer.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)

        # Button to clear the console output
        self.clearer = tk.Button(self.bottom, text="Clear", command=self.clear)
        self.clearer.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)

        # Button to stop the running script
        self.stopper = tk.Button(self.bottom, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stopper.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)

        self.bottom.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

    def clear_text(self):
        """Clears the Text widget"""
        self.text.config(state="normal")
        self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
        self.text.config(state="disabled")

    def clear(self, event=None):
        """Just clears the Text widget."""
        self.clear_text()

    def show(self, message):
        """Inserts message into the Text widget"""
        self.text.config(state="normal")
        self.text.insert("end", message + "\n")
        self.text.see("end")
        self.text.config(state="disabled")

    def start_thread(self, event=None):
        """Starts a new thread and calls process"""
        self.stop()
        self.running = True
        self.command = "C:/Python/python.exe C:/Python/afaina-evobliss-software-68090c0edb16/automatizace/script_run.py"
        threading.Thread(target=self.process).start()

    def process(self):
        """Runs the script and handles output/input"""
        self.popen = Popen(self.command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True, shell=True)
        
        while self.running:
            self.execute()
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Sleep to prevent busy waiting

    def execute(self):
        """Keeps inserting line by line into self.text the output of the execution of self.command"""
        if self.popen is not None:
            line = self.popen.stdout.readline()  # Čtení řádku výstupu skriptu
            print(line)
            if line:
            # Vykreslení otázky a její zobrazení
               
                self.show(line.strip())  # Zobrazení výstupu
                self.text.update()  # Aktualizace GUI, aby se výstup vykreslil okamžitě

        # Kontrola, zda výstup nevyžaduje vstup od uživatele
                if line.strip().endswith(":"):  # Kontrola pro koncovou dvojtečku
                    self.show("Waiting for input...")  # Zobrazení zprávy "Čeká na vstup"
                    self.input_entry.focus()  # Přesunutí kurzoru do vstupního pole
                    self.input_entry.update()  # Aktualizace GUI pro vstupní pole

    # Kontrola, zda proces skončil
            if self.popen.poll() is not None:
                self.show(f"Process '{self.command}' terminated.\n\n")
                self.stop()


    def send_input(self, event=None):
        """Send input from Entry to the running process"""
        if self.popen and self.popen.stdin:
            user_input = self.input_entry.get() + "\n"
            self.popen.stdin.write(user_input)
            self.popen.stdin.flush()  # Ensure input is sent immediately
            self.input_entry.delete(0, 'end')  # Clear input field

    def stop(self):
        """Stops the running process if it's active"""
        if self.popen:
            try:
                self.popen.kill()
            except ProcessLookupError:
                pass
        self.running = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Console")
    console = Console(root)
    console.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()


As you can see, I tried searching for input using ":" because my inputs end with ":".
Thank you for your help

The problem is that popen.stdout.readline() waits for a new line but there isn't a new line printed after the ahoj: . Try reading character by character using popen.stdout.read(1).

Thank you so much, read(1) works, but it writes each letter on a separate line, and if I choose read(100), it does not work

Try also removing the + "\n" in the show method. I think that's adding the unwanted newlines.

it did this
1.Mixingtwoliquids.2.Dividingalargervolumeintoxbeakers.Toselect,enteradigitwithoutadotonthefollowinglineWritethedigityouchoose:Waiting for input...
is it better, but I have no idea how to put each print in each row with a gap between the letters

My bad. I didn't notice that you have .strip() in self.show(line.strip()). That's what is removing the newlines.

Omg you are the best, thank you so so much
